# Sending recurring reminders through text message at user-defined times in ASP.NET Core 7 and Angular 14

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, twilio-api, quartz.net, hangfire

I've been stuck on a problem for a couple of days and I think I'm getting in my own head a little bit regarding a solution so I figured getting another view might be helpful for me

I've created a .NET Core 7 and Angular 15 app for sending recurring medication reminders through text to users at their own defined time periods. I was able to leverage the Twilio messaging API to send a text message with little issues, however I've ran into a logical roadblock where I'm not sure how exactly to send multiple recurring texts at the same user-specified time on different days.

I know Hangfire is another resource I can leverage, however I'm not sure if it's possible to dynamically populate the Cron job time parameter in Program.cs to match what the user has entered. I also looked into Quartz and ran into a similar logical roadblock. I'm thinking the best way to do this is get the time stamp to run a job from the DB, and pass it into the job scheduler (either using Quartz or Hangfire), and then schedule the task to send the text message that way. However I'm not sure if this is possible for multiple users, or users with multiple reminders...

Here is the code I've written that sends a text message using Twilio's API:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("SendText")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendSms([FromBody] SmsMessage sms)
{
    var message = MessageResource.Create(
        messagingServiceSid: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        to: new PhoneNumber(sms.To),
        from: new PhoneNumber(sms.From),
        body: sms.Message,
        scheduleType: MessageResource.ScheduleTypeEnum.Fixed,
        statusCallback: new Uri("placeholder_uri.com"),
        sendAt: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(16),
        client: _client); // pass in the custom client
    
    return Ok("Success");
}
```

One solution I tried was setting the Callback url to be the same method that I'm using to send the text message, however it fails since the sms object being passed in is null the second time it's being called. I'm thinking the best solution would be to remove this callback, and instead run this code during a Hangfire Cron job and getting the message from the DB itself if that's possible but I just wanted to see if there's something obvious I may be missing...

If anyone has any pointers it would be greatly appreciated, I think I may be overthinking myself out of a solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: store the requests in a database or a queue. then periodically check for those requests then send the data.

Answer (score 0):

By time periods, you do mean schedules like CRON jobs right, not one off scheduled jobs?

Either way, Hangfire does let you create CRON jobs ad-hoc and schedule on off jobs too. Here's an example of a Hangfire application where CRON jobs are created and removed from console input:

```cs
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a command:");
    var command = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (command)
    {
        case "s":
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a schedule:");
            var schedule = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an ID:");
            var id = Console.ReadLine();
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
                id,
                () => Console.WriteLine("Ahoy!"), 
                schedule
            );
            break;
        }
        case "r":
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an ID:");
            var id = Console.ReadLine();
            RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(id);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing is that you need to give a unique ID to the CRON job so you can unschedule or update it when the user changes their schedule.

[Here's the full code](https://gist.github.com/Swimburger/532e390c9e1b17c700576282cfbf6db7).

---

As you show in your code, there's scheduling functionality in Twilio's Messaging API, but it's limited between 15 min and 7 days from now, and limited to scheduled 500,000 messages at a single time.
If the user changes their schedule, you also have to cancel the existing scheduled messages.
So, it's doable with message scheduling if your users' schedules fall in between that range and you schedule them weekly.

However, I think the Hangfire solution is easier to develop and maintain.
Quartz.NET may have the same functionality, but I'm not as familiar with it.